# Why some Dart built-in types start with capital letter(List, Map, String) and others with lower letter(number, int, double, bool)?

Tags: dart, types, naming-conventions

Is it Java ancestry or is it collection related?
Is there a pattern and how `dynamic` type fits in it?

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/1410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically languages like Java and C# have categorized the types into 2 main categories:

1. primitive types (`int`, `char`, `bool`, `long`, `double` etc)
2. user-defined types (`List`, `Map`, `Future`, `Animal`, `Car` etc)

To set the difference clearly, the convention has been to follow **CamelCase** i.e. starting with a capitalized character for `user-defined types` and follow **pascalCase** for `primitive ones`

`dart`, like lot of other features takes this convention from these 2 languages.

**NOTE:** The `String` type has been a special case for a long time. C# has both a type named `string` and an alias type named `String`. Java however takes the C++ philosophy and doesn't consider `String` as a primitive type. Hence uses **CamelCase**. For String `dart`  has followed the java path.

**PS** [This GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/1410) discusses about the `String` issue in detail.

Answer (score 4):

Dart chose the naming for its *familiarity* for people coming from Java. That's why `int`, `double`, `void` and `bool` are lower-case even though they are not "primitive" types in Dart (and even if `bool` was made shorter than the Java `boolean` type.)
The `num` class does not exist in `Java`, but it follows `int` and `double` types for consistency.
The `dynamic` type was probably just lower-cased for convenience, and because it was actually a non-class type.